# Unable to resolve module socketcluster

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

React-native newbie here, I'm trying to start an app with genymotion emulator (android 6) but I get the error below.

My friend who is also working on it can start it without this problem. I have tried starting another app (AwesomeProject) and it runs fine, so my environment should be ok. Any suggestions to help me track down the error would be very welcome :)

Bundling `index.android.js`
  Transforming modules  ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░  96.2% (1205/1230)...(node:9744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1733): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module D:\Projets\DrinkFinder\react\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.j\lib\ws-browser.js from D:\Projets\DrinkFinder\react\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.js: Directory D:\Projets\DrinkFinder\react\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lBundling `index.android.js`
  Analysing...

Comment: Isn't it more natural to copy-paste text of error itself instead of doing picture? I'm even not talking about that someone who would like to answer on question probably wants to copy text error.

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on Windows 10?

I had the same issue and found the issue on Github:
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools/issues/62#issuecomment-271882723

You have to downgrade remote-redux-devtools to version 0.5.0.
You can do this with:

```
    yarn add remote-redux-devtools@0.5.0 --dev
```

or

```
    npm install remote-redux-devtools@0.5.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: Yes running on windows 10, will try this out tonight, thanks :)